# Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable' why?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'

what is the problem that make this slider not working ? in this page http://saqacc.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with wordpress but you have another error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Looking in your DOM reveals that you are including jquery-ui.min.js before the jquery framework. This line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=3.5"></script>
```

should be after the jquery.js inclusion.

It is an order issue in your js files inclusion. Because jQuery is not defined when parsing jquery-ui, the jquery-draggable widget is not defined and so your call to the draggable widget can't work

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included jQuery core, but only jQuery UI. If you check the console you'll see:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

So include jQuery after jQuery UI and it will work eg.:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery UI needs jQuery to works properly:

> jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects,
>   widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.
>   Whether you're building highly interactive web applications or you
>   just need to add a date picker to a form control, jQuery UI is the
>   perfect choice.